# Different face colors in one patch object in Matlab

Tags: matlab, plot

I am attempting to create a scene in Matlab programmatically, adding randomly oriented objects for scene evaluation. I am using patch objects for display, so I have lines like `myObject.Faces = [data]`, `myObject.Vertices = [data]`, etc. If I want to add points to the scene I just append the new object with the following snippet:

```
myScene.Vertices = [myScene.Vertices; myObject.Vertices];
myScene.Faces = [myScene.Faces; myObjects.Faces + numel(myScene.Faces)];
```

So far, for the basic scene, everything works out just fine. My issue comes when I want to be able to visually distinguish new objects in the scene. I can't seem to color the objects I've appended to the scene individually - everything has to be the same color.

I've tried using `repmat` to create a color entry to correspond with every entry in `<var>.Faces`, but I get an error that `Color value must be a 3 element numeric vector`.

I understand that I may be able to get by using a structure array and looping through every element, but I was hoping to avoid that. I have many objects I'm trying to track and I'd like to refer to the scene as `myScene`, so I can plot with `patch(myScene)`, so math on `myScene.Vertices`, etc.

I really don't want to wind up with:

```
for i = 1:numel(myScene)
  myScene(i).Vertices = <some function>(myScene(i).Vertices);
  patch(myScene(i))
  hold on
end
```

every single time I need to interact with `myScene`, but again, I'd like different objects in the scene to be colored differently as well.

**:EDIT:**

Okay, for an *extremely* simplistic example, try this:

```
sceneX = [-5 5 5 -5 5 -5];
sceneY = [5 5 -5 5 -5 -5];
sceneZ = [0 0 0 0 0 0];
scene.Vertices = [sceneX.',sceneY.',sceneZ.'];
nPoints = size(scene.Vertices,1);
scene.Faces = reshape(1:nPoints,3,nPoints/3).';
scene.FaceColor = [0.7 0.7 0.7];
patch(scene)

objectX = [-1 -1  1 -1  1  1 -1 -1  0 -1  0  1  0  1  1 -1  0  1];
objectY = [-1  1  1 -1  1 -1 -1  1  0  1  0  1  0  1 -1 -1  0 -1];
objectZ = [ 1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  3  1  3  1  3  1  1  1  3  1];
object.Vertices = [objectX.',objectY.',objectZ.'];
nPoints = size(object.Vertices,1);
object.Faces = reshape(1:nPoints,3,nPoints/3).';
object.FaceColor = [0.3 0.3 0.7];
hold on
patch(object)
```

Now, as I wrote above, I can add `object` to `scene` by:

```
newScene.Vertices = [scene.Vertices; object.Vertices];
newScene.Faces = [scene.Faces; object.Faces + numel(scene.Faces)];
```

However, I cannot keep the colors - everything has to be set as one color, as far as I can tell. This is a very basic example; the scene I'm actually generating has hundreds of objects, each with hundreds of faces.

What I'm looking for: The answer I will select immediately as correct is the one that explains how to do (1) below, or will explain why (1) isn't possible and provide how to do (2) instead.

(1) - Explain how to assign colors to each set of faces, as arbitrarily assigned by me, in `newScene` using the [patch(FV)](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/patch.html) version of the `patch` command. In the example above, I would like `newScene.Faces(1:2,:)` to be one color, and `newScene.Faces(3:end,:)` to be another color.

(2) - Explain how to assign colors to each set of faces, as arbitrarily assigned by me, in `newScene` using any variant of the the `patch` command.

I have a lot of my other functions looking specifically for the `FV` structure, and given the very large size of my scene I don't want to track/maintain two duplicate entries for the same scene. Modifying all of my other functions will be moderately painful, and if it's required then I guess I have to do it, but I'd like to know *why* I have to do it if it is required.

Comment: How did you create the colormap for each face? it seems that the error is there. show us that piece of code. (try transposing what you arleady have also)

Comment: I don't create a colormap for each face, I use `myObject.FaceColor = objectColor`, where `objectColor = [R G B]`.

Comment: Post the code for that part, it should work. If it doesn't it can be because  `patch` expects a `Nx3` array and you are putting a `3xN` for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to specify a color for each face you have to use the patch property `FaceVertexCData` (which can be defined in a structure with a field of the same name), and also set `FaceColor` to `'Flat'`, as described in the [Coloring Patches](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/patch.html#br92bi7-17) documentation.

So your example become:

```
%%
sceneX = [-5 5 5 -5 5 -5];
sceneY = [5 5 -5 5 -5 -5];
sceneZ = [0 0 0 0 0 0];
scene.Vertices = [sceneX.',sceneY.',sceneZ.'];
nPoints = size(scene.Vertices,1);
scene.Faces = reshape(1:nPoints,3,nPoints/3).';
scene.FaceColor = 'Flat' ;
scene.FaceVertexCData = repmat( [0.7 0.7 0.7] , size(scene.Faces,1) , 1 ) ; %// assign the same color for each face
patch(scene)

objectX = [-1 -1  1 -1  1  1 -1 -1  0 -1  0  1  0  1  1 -1  0  1];
objectY = [-1  1  1 -1  1 -1 -1  1  0  1  0  1  0  1 -1 -1  0 -1];
objectZ = [ 1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  3  1  3  1  3  1  1  1  3  1];
object.Vertices = [objectX.',objectY.',objectZ.'];
nPoints = size(object.Vertices,1);
object.Faces = reshape(1:nPoints,3,nPoints/3).';
object.FaceColor = 'Flat' ;
object.FaceVertexCData = repmat( [0.3 0.3 0.7] , size(object.Faces,1) , 1 ) ; %// assign the same color for each face
hold on
patch(object)

%%
newScene.Vertices  = [scene.Vertices ; object.Vertices];
newScene.Faces     = [scene.Faces    ; object.Faces + numel(scene.Faces)];
newScene.FaceVertexCData = [scene.FaceVertexCData ; object.FaceVertexCData ] ;
newScene.FaceColor = 'Flat' ;
patch(newScene)
```

Now your `newScene` structure has a field `FaceVertexCData` containing an `8x3` matrix representing the color of each faces (the first 2 rows for the faces of `scene` and the next 6 rows for the faces of `object`). You can change each face color individually by changing the corresponding row of this matrix.

If you want to change the color of one object, you have to change all the rows corresponding to the faces of this object, so it may be good to keep track of which face/row correspond to which object as you are adding them.

Comment: Awesome thanks! I had tried using `FaceVertexCData` before, but I didn't realize that `FaceColor` had to be set to `'Flat'` in addition. The documentation on the `patch` command is, in my opinion, very hard to follow.